# Unique key for DoubleClick (DFP) data to Google Analytics Data in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, double-click, double-click-advertising

I have daily exports of both DoubleClick (DFP/Google Ad Manager) data and Google Analytics 360 set up for BigQuery. These are linked on my Google Analytics account, so can view ad manager data from within the analytics GUI.

However when I look at the session data there doesn't seem to be any unique key to join the two datasets. Is there a way to join these two datasets in bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the same column names to join tables

```
with

transactions as (
    select
        *
    from
        unnest(
            array[
                struct(
                    'xxx' as pos_id,
                    1 as transaction_id,
                    date'2019-06-20' as transaction_date,
                    200 as amount),

                struct('xxx', 2, date'2019-07-30', 1000),
                struct('xxx', 3, date'2019-04-10', 500),
                struct('xxx', 4, date'2019-05-15', 2000)
            ]
        )
),

cashbacks as (
    select
        *
    from
        unnest(
            array[
                struct(
                    'xxx' as pos_id,
                    date'2019-01-01' as start_date,
                    date'2019-04-30' as end_date,
                    0.1 as cashback),

                struct('xxx', date'2019-07-01', date'2019-09-30', 0.2)
            ]
        )
)


select
    t.*,
    c.* except(pos_id)
from
    transactions as t
    left join cashbacks as c
        on  t.pos_id = c.pos_id
            and t.transaction_date between  c.start_date
                                            and c.end_date
order by
    1, 3 desc
```